# Script to extract/cut contents from a log file into a new file

Tags: windows-10, windows-scripting

I have a log file that captures data and timestamps it, but it doesn't have a date stamp. So it ends up looking like the below with the newest information at the very bottom.

```
[01:10:01:943] numbers/words/etc
[23:55:53:505] numbers/words/etc
[00:15:43:432] numbers/words/etc
[23:54:01:442] numbers/words/etc
```

What I am trying to do is move the first "day" using the timestamps and moving it to a new file name with the current date and leaving the new "day" intact, below is what I want I am needing it to look like after it runs.

Original File

```
[00:15:43:432] numbers/words/etc
[23:54:01:442] numbers/words/etc
```

New File.Month_Day_Year

```
[01:10:01:943] numbers/words/etc
[23:55:53:505] numbers/words/etc
```

Any help would be very appreciated as I am relatively new to scripting as a whole and am trying to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74381462.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET /a fileseq=0
SET "line="

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "!line!" gtr "%%e" SET /a fileseq+=1
 ECHO %%e>>"%outfile%.!fileseq!"
 SET "line=%%e"
)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Splits the file into parts for each day. Since it appears possible that more than one day's data is contained in the file, applying a date is debatable. The number of files produced is in `fileseq`.

Just while I think of it, my sceme would be:

```
ren "%filename1%" newdata
type newdata>>dregs
rem now process dregs which is dregs from previous run+newdata
move "%outfile%.%fileseq%" dregs
del newdata
```

So - incomplete data from the prior run is moved to `dregs`, then append new data - process and generate a new dregs file.

Comment: Good morning

I went ahead and gave this a try and it worked to copy information over to the a new file, but it didn't remove the information from the old file as well as it copied the entire contents from the original file instead of just the "previous days".  

Would you know a way that would remove the content from the previous file as well?

Comment: I appreciate your assistance Magoo, I found a way to clear the previous contents of the file as well. Have a wonderful rest of your day!

Comment: Just as I was about to create my own scheme...